# Can the value of an undefined and non-initialized class attribute be assigned to variable?

Tags: python, tuples

I may say first that I'm new to python. I'm trying to understand how this sample of code of a bigger project works. To be more specific here is the class _TokenType which is subtypping tuple, at some point is created a _TokenType object with the name Token inside the _TokenType class, which means Token is a tuple too. I hope I get it right so far, if not please correct me. Right after the creation of Token there is a creation of a new variable Text which has the value of the attribute Text of  _TokenType, as I see it.

```
class _TokenType(tuple):
   .
   .# code, code, code
   .
   Token = _TokenType()

   # Special token types
   Text = Token.Text
```

My problems are:

1. That there is no Text attribute defined in _TokenType. I know that in python you can add dynamically new attributes but it still doesn't make sense to me, since Token.Text nowhere in the rest of the module had a value asigned to it.
2. Even if Text is somehow an attribute of _TokenType why does it start with an upper-case letter?

I'm really confused and I would really appreciate some help on that. Thank you for your time.

**Edit**: 
I should have also post the **getattr** method to be complete, which explains the above behavior, as Duncan pointed out.

```
 def __getattr__(self, val):
    if not val or not val[0].isupper():
        return tuple.__getattribute__(self, val)
    new = _TokenType(self + (val,))
    setattr(self, val, new)
    new.parent = self
    return new
```

Comment: That's quite a weird looking piece of code you've got there. Could it be that the indentation is wrong? Try to post a more self contained example. As it is now, it doesn't work.

Comment: You're right @siebz0r, I posted an edit about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking about this file: https://github.com/isnowfy/pydown/blob/master/pygments/token.py

The class defines a method `__getattr__` that defines the action to be taken when looking up an attribute (like `Text`) that doesn't already exist as an attribute of the class.

```
def __getattr__(self, val):
    if not val or not val[0].isupper():
        return tuple.__getattribute__(self, val)
    new = _TokenType(self + (val,))
    setattr(self, val, new)
    self.subtypes.add(new)
    new.parent = self
    return new
```

When you access `Token.Text` this will result in a call to `Token.__getattr__('Text')`. The method checks that the first character of the attribute name is uppercase and creates a new attribute called 'Text' which is itself a `_TokentType` with `Token` as its parent.

Comment: I should have also post the overriden method __getattr__ . Yet, that was exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you so much for the rather intuitive answer.